# How to NSData to NSDictionary?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdictionary

I have tried this solution I found here, but it is not working and I keep getting this error:

> (*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb7286f36c0')

I am saving NSDictionary to Core data after converting it to NSData then my Fetch looks like this.

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context :NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let noteDict = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "NoteDictionary")
                noteDict.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


            let dicResults : NSArray
            try! dicResults = context.executeFetchRequest(noteDict)

            var tempData:NSData
                tempData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dicResults)

            let tempString = NSString(data: tempData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let unArchDictionary : NSDictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(tempData)! as? NSDictionary
```

it is crashing on the `let unArchDictionary` ...
Any help please !!

JZ

Comment: Hi, i thought this line was unarchiving the object ? took out the ! still crashes.  let unArchDictionary : NSDictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(tempData)as? NSDictionary

Comment: You didn't do what I said! You took out the exclamation mark but you didn't take out the `:NSDictionary?` as I told you to. That's why you're still crashing. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did see that after and fixed the issue , also posted a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your own code:

```
let dicResults : NSArray // dicResults is an array
// ... 
var tempData:NSData // tempData is an NSData
tempData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dicResults)
// so tempData is an array archived into an NSData
// ...
let unArchDictionary : NSDictionary? =
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(tempData)! as? NSDictionary
// now you are unarchiving tempData as a dictionary?!
```

How do you expect to put an NSArray *into* the archive and yet get an NSDictionary *out* of the same archive?

Comment: You have asked 18 questions but only once have you _accepted_ an answer. That is not good behavior on Stack Overflow. People are not going to want to help you if you don't accept their answers. If you haven't gotten an acceptable answer, you should edit your question to be better. If you have gotten an acceptable answer, you should accept it (checkmark).

Comment: +1 Additionally someone who is searching a solution for a similar problem will see the Q with not accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for the record I do up check when I validate someone has helped me. However i solved my own issue.

If you want to save NSMutableDictionary to Core data and retrieve it here is the solution..    ***FYI i am using Transformable for my Attribute..***                                                           Saving to Core Data....                                                            //  Setting up ManagedObjectContext

```
 let appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let dict = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("NoteDictionary", inManagedObjectContext: context)

let tempNote = self.noteField!.text as NSString
noteDictionary.setObject(tempNote, forKey: dicKey)

[dict .setValue(noteDictionary, forKey: "dictionary")]

// print("The Note Dictionary has this in it ",noteDictionary)

do {
    try context.save()
     print("The Note That Was Saved is ",dict)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Now Retrieving from Core Data

```
func showLabel() {

let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context :NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
let noteDict = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "NoteDictionary")
noteDict.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

let dicResults : NSArray
try! dicResults = context.executeFetchRequest(noteDict)

    for context in dicResults {
        noteDictionary = context.valueForKey("dictionary")as! NSMutableDictionary
        noteField?.text = noteDictionary.valueForKey(dicKey as String)as? String
    }
}
```